# Get GridRow value when click edit button using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a grid which is binding hiddenfield, image and edit button in a template field.
I tried to get the hiddenfield value when I click the edit button using javascript.
but I always get the same id value on each row edit button click.

here is my code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdEmployeeDts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="No Data Added" Width="100%" CellPadding="4" CssClass="table table-hover table-nomargin dataTable dataTable-columnfilter"                            GridLines="None">
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
<input type="hidden"  value='<%# Eval("recordId") %>'id="hdnfldId">    </input>

<button id="btnProfile" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" title="View" ><%# Eval("firstName").ToString()+" "+Eval("lastName").ToString()%></button>

<button class="btn btn-mini btn-warning " id='btnEdit' title="Edit" onclick="javascript:edit();return false;" > <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit</button>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>



<script type="text/javascript">

   function edit()
   {
        var id = $('#hdnfldId').val();
       console.log(id);
   }

</script>
```

I am beginning with JavaScript. I want to get hidden field value when I click Grid row edit button.
Help me pls

Thank you in advance

Comment: `function edit()
   {
       var id = $(this).prev().prev().val();
       console.log(id);
   }`

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
  var id =$(this).parent('tr').find('#hdnfldId').val();
  console.log(id);
```

just paste your table structure, this helps other to answer easliy